# How to connect to external SSH server by node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ssh, automation

want to connect to another linux server that need SSH connection directly from my Node JS code and to fire some commands like to stop a service and etc using some npm package like "cmd-npm".

But when I trying to do it I can't handling the password authentication immediately after connecting.

I've tried to using npm ssh2 package but I can't pass commands inside the server only to connect to it.

Is there any ideal solution for my use case?

This is the code:

```
 cmd.get(
    `
    ssh username@host_ip
    cd ..
    ls
`, function (err, data, stderr) {
         await console.log('the current working dir is : ', data)
         if (err) throw await err;
    }
);
```

Comment: Try use `expect` to input anything after `ssh`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use ssh key?

Comment: I don't understand this, particularly the last part: "I've tried to using npm ssh2 package but I can't pass commands inside the server only to connect to it."

Comment: already tried that, didn't work :/\